# HTML Removing all Tags

Tags: java, html, loops, tags, indexof

Thanks to all who responded to my previous question.

I'm trying to write a method removeAllTags for the HTMLProcessor class. The method deals only with a subset of HTML tabs: it assumes that a given text contains only complete simple tags, such as  and  or  and , where a closing tag differs from the 
corresponding opening tag only by the “/” character after “<”. The closing tag must come after the opening tag. The method returns the text with all tags removed (or the original text if no tags were found). The method should return the original text if the tags in text do not match (no closing tag found after an opening tag).

I already wrote 2 methods, one is called "findFirstTag" and the other one is "remove".
I'm puzzled on this method and it's somewhat confusing to me. I know I have to implement the previous two methods, and I tried doing this (so you can see) with a while loop - which ultimately failed. Can anyone help me? It is greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
    public static String findFirstTag(String text) {
    int firstIndex = text.indexOf("<");
    if (firstIndex >= 0) {
        String newText = text.substring(firstIndex);
        int secondIndex = newText.indexOf(">");

        return text.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex + 1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static String remove(String text, String str) {

    int firstIndex = text.indexOf(str);
    int beginofNewIndex = (firstIndex + 1) + str.length();

    if (firstIndex >= 0) {
        return text.substring(0, firstIndex) + text.substring(beginofNewIndex);
    } else {
        return text;
    }
}

public static String removeAllTags(String text) {

    String revisedText = text;
    int textlastIndex = text.length() + 1;

    while (textlastIndex > 2) {

        revisedText = remove(revisedText, findFirstTag(revisedText));
        textlastIndex = textlastIndex - 1;
    }

    return revisedText;

}
}
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: My method removeAllTags does not seem to work...can you give me a hint how to proceed? Thanks